# mod_rewrite: the precedence of [OR] and implicit [AND]

Tags: mod-rewrite, operator-precedence

Is it possible to check for **X and (Y or Z)** with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)?

I have the following rule to serve dummy.png to guests of my website, who don't have 2 cookies **id** and **auth** set (I set those in my custom Drupal module for registered users):

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !auth [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !id
   RewriteRule .+ /images/dummy.png [L]
```

but I'm not sure if it works as intended (maybe it acts as **(X and Y) or Z** instead?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let the RewriteRule handle the URI pattern matching. No need to do that in a RewriteCond. For other URLs, the first two conditions may match, but the rule itself won't and no rewrite will take place.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !auth [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !id
RewriteRule ^/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-.+ /images/dummy.png [L]
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this just doesn't work on Apache 2.2.15... Removin g [L] does not help either.